# Trying to identify the goal of an algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I have this algorithm, A and B are the addresses of of two different binary trees' roots.

Each node has a value, pointer to left sub-tree and pointer to right sub-tree.

Here is the algorithm:

```
foo(A,B){

    if (A == NULL){
        return B;
    }
    if (B != NULL){
        if(A->value > B->value){
            return foo(B,A);
        }
        B->left = foo(A->right,B->left);
        A->right = B;
    }
    return A;
}
```

I did manage to understand it's merging tree B to the right sub-tree of tree A,
however i did not manager to understand the regularity of the values.

Hope you could help me with this one, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the intent is to take two sorted binary trees and combine them into a single sorted binary tree.

The key is the comparison `if(A->value > B->value)`. This branch ensures that the `A` parameter will always contain the lesser value at the point in which the subtrees are merged, which forces an ordering on the result.

Since `A->left` and `B->right` are never traversed by this algorithm, there appears to be the some additional requirements on the two trees provided. One possibility is that they are expected not to have overlapping ranges. That is, the smallest value of one tree must be greater than the largest value of the other. Or the requirement may be some other thing similar to this involving the contents of the subtrees. Or perhaps the type of the value is restricted to two values, like a Boolean.

Comment: What's a `sorted binary tree`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what's happening in case the given binary trees aren't sorted?

Comment: @IVlad - A sorted binary tree is one in which all of the elements of the left subtree are (in some sense) “less-than” all of the elements of the right subtree, and the node itself is between. In this arrangement, an in-order traversal ( `traverse(A->left), A.value, traverse(A->right)` ) will produce a sorted list.

Comment: Oh, so a binary search tree. Sorry, never heard them called sorted binary trees! Note that your condition is not sufficient: the left and right subtrees must in turn be binary search trees / sorted binary trees themselves. Only then will an inorder traversal produce a sorted list.

Comment: @argamanza - I do not believe the resulting tree will be sorted if the initial trees are not sorted.

Comment: @IVlad - Yes, I should have added that that condition must hold for all subtrees. Also, you're right about "binary search tree". I've been out of school for nearly twenty years, and my terminology is getting soft!

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge Thanks, so can i say that if both of the trees are BST it will merge them into one BST, and if not it will merge them into the right branch in a random order?